# Animation time problem

Tags: manipulate, animation

I have a problem with `Manipulate`. I want to stop my animation depending on a condition on the value `A`, which is  controlled by a manipulator. I tried to do this by giving the animator specified for variable `x` the option `AnimationRunning -> If[Tan[A] <= 0.7, False, True]`. That stopped the animation, but didn't stop the animation clock, which depends on the computer's real-clock time. So when the animation is restarted by increasing `A` above 0.7, the animation jumps to the place determined by the current clock time, which didn't stop while the graphics updating was paused.

I think I need to stop the animation clock when the graphics updating is paused. My idea is to get access to `PlayPauseButton` to click it in code.  But i have no idea how to do it..

I will be grateful for any help.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {
   {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], AASTriangle[Pi/2, A, 1]},
   Translate[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.004], Blue}],
      Rotate[{{Rectangle[{0, Sin[A] + 0.006}, {0.15, 
           Sin[A] + 0.08}]}}, -A, {0, Sin[A]}]}},
    {x*Cos[A], -x*Sin[A]}
    ]
   },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 400}
  ],
 {{A, Pi/4, "A"}, 0.0001, Pi/2 - 0.0001},
 {{x, 0}, 0, 1 - 0.15, ControlType -> Animator, 
  AnimationRunning -> If[Tan[A] <= 0.7, False, True], 
  AnimationRunTime -> Dynamic[t], AnimationTimeIndex -> Dynamic[indx]},
 Dynamic[x],
 Dynamic[t],
 Dynamic[indx],
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I've implemented animations that required the level of control you are seeking, but I could never figure out how to do it with `Manipulate` or `Animate`. I had to fall back on the lower level construct `DynamicModule` and implement updating the graphics from the system clock by calling `AbsoluteTime`. It wasn't all that hard, but I had to implement my own Play, Pause, and Reset buttons. You might do the same for your code, unless someone smarter than me comes up with a way to do with `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I think I found solution. Maybe someone someday will be need it. It is not exactly what i wanted but it works properly

```
Manipulate[
 {Animator[Dynamic[x], {0, 1 - 0.15}, 
   AnimationRunning -> If[A <= 0.7, False, True], 
   AnimationRunTime -> Dynamic[ti]],
  Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], 
     AASTriangle[Pi/2, A, 1]},
    Translate[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.004], Blue}],
       Rotate[{{Rectangle[{0, Sin[A] + 0.006}, {0.15, 
            Sin[A] + 0.08}]}}, -A, {0, Sin[A]}]}}, {Dynamic[x]*
       Cos[A], -Dynamic[x]*Sin[A]}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}]},
 {{A, Pi/4, "A"}, 0.0001, Pi/2 - 0.0001},
 Dynamic[ti], ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: The trouble with this solution is the one that forced me use DynamicModule: it destroys the functionality of the animator's Pause / Play button. You can get the  rectangle moving below the critical angle with the Pause / Play button which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what is desired.  The basic idea is to keep track of how long it is paused because the angle of inclination is too shallow.

```
With[{$defaultDuration = 5., x1 = 0., x2 = 1 - 0.15},
 Manipulate[
  With[{x = Mod[xx + dx, 1 - 0.15]},
   Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], AASTriangle[Pi/2, A, 1]}, 
     Translate[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.004], Blue}], 
        Rotate[{{Rectangle[{0, Sin[A] + 0.006}, {0.15, Sin[A] + 0.08}]}},
           -A, {0, Sin[A]}]}}, {x*Cos[A], -x*Sin[A]}]},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {400,400}]
   ],
  {{A, Pi/4, "A"}, 0.0001, Pi/2 - 0.0001},
  {{xx, 0, HoldForm[x]}, x1, x2, ControlType -> Animator,
   AnimationRate -> Dynamic[rate],
   AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[running && If[Tan[A] <= 0.7,
       If[state, iOld = indx]; state = False,
       True], (running = #) &],
   AnimationRunTime -> Dynamic[t],
   AnimationTimeIndex -> Dynamic[indx,
     (indx = #; If[! state, state = True; dx += (iOld - indx)*rate]) &],
   DefaultDuration -> $defaultDuration},
  {{state, True}, None}, {{running, True}, None},
  {{rate, (x2 - x1)/$defaultDuration}, None}, {{iOld, 0.}, None},
  {{dx, 0.}, None}, {{indx, 0.}, None},
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
 ]
```

The initial `With` was used to better show the dependencies on `DefaultDuration` and the length of the interval for the animation variable `x` (or in my code `xx`). It is not a necessary feature of the code.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is the one that forced me use `DynamicModule`: it destroys the functionality of the animator's Pause and Play buttons. Try to use those buttons in your `Manipulate` panel. You will see what I mean.

Comment: @m_goldberg That's a feature of the OP that was not mentioned as a problem.  I considered just using `Clock` instead of `Animator`, which would seem to me to give a more natural user-interface.  I've updated the code so that the pause/play and the animation rate buttons operate properly.

Comment: The revised code is very nice and  I have up-voted it. I think it satisfies all my objections. If I were the OP, this would be the answer I would accept.